# how to remove tomcat port number 8080 from localhost url using java code in web aplication

Tags: java

when i run a any web aplication on any server that have default port like 
**http://localhost:8080/demo/**
But i want hide or remove 8080 port number from our aplication using java code like   **http://localhost/demo/** from whole application

Comment: You can either change the port in Tomcat settings or use a reverse proxy (e.g. Apache HTTP server) in front of your application. Either way, your questions is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change it using Java code. HTTP uses port 80 by default. Your server deviates from that by running on port 8080. So this alternate port number must be mentioned in the url. In order to get rid of it you need to make the server accessible via port 80.

You can simply change the port to "80" instead the tomcat's default "8080" in the server.xml file in the tomcat conf folder. More info: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/server.html

Or you can use a Reverse Proxy running on port 80 forwarding requests to port 8080. If you use Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html